# Message Kit controlling which side each image shows up on

Tags: ios, swift, chat, messagekit

I am using the MessageKit to create a real time chat in my Swift App. One issue I am getting is, I want my chat from the user to be on the left, and the chat from the person they are talking to, to be on the right. As of now this is flipped, and I am unsure what function that is being set in, or if this is just default and there isn't a way to change it. I see functions for changing the direction of the bubbles, and avatar location but nothing to quickly fix which side each new message goes on. Can someone help me figure out this issue. Here is what it currently looks like:[image]

But instead I would want the second image to be orange and on the right side, and the orange text to be silver and on the left side. Thanks!

I feel like this should be a quick fix, I am just unsure which like function likely part of the deleagte that I can change, as it is my first time using this messageKit library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix everything but on MessagesDataSource protocol there is isFromCurrentSender

just reverse the return from that and I believe that most of the components use that function for layout.

Comment: Yupp this is what I did, except it was in the CurrentSender function, I don't know if you accidentally said the wrong name or if that is a different function but this worked for me! Only problem I now face which isn't a huge issue, but in my database, all the messages have the wrong sender ID attached to them. Since I had to flip the logic in the CurrentSender function.

Comment: Thats why you need to update the isFromCurrentSender instead of the CurrentSender function.
https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Sources/Protocols/MessagesDataSource.swift#L42